# Reading Request Cokkie in Jmeter Groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell

Below is the piece of code from Java Script(K6) that returns me Cookie.
I am trying to do the same in JMeter Groovy language.

```
 let sso = JSON.stringify(response.request.cookies[`mygateid_sso`]);
 let authToken_regex = /{'authToken':'(\S+?)'}/;
 authToken = sso.match(authToken_regex)[0];
```

I am not finding a way to read `response.request.cookies`

Answer (score 1):

In JMeter you have neither `JSON` as it's not a part of Nashorn engine nor `response.request.cookies`

If you want to access your `mygateid_sso` cookie the easiest way is:

1. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
2. Add the [next line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous) to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```
3. Restart JMeter to pick up the change
4. That's it, you should be able to access your cookie as `${COOKIE_mygateid_sso}` where required

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)

Comment: Thanks, it helps. Cookie contains lots of things. Is it possible to extract token from this cookie and set it as Cookie.   headers: {
      'Accept': '*/*',
      'Cookie': 'sso="' + authToken + '"'
    },